# "ols" function using Matlabcontrol API ( JMI )

Tags: matlab

I am trying to call matlab `ols` function using Matlabcontrol API `JMI`. `ols` requires 2 arrays , when I pass 3 parameters in to `returningFeval`, my 1st param is `ols`, 2nd is 1 ,  3rd param is the object[] of 2 arrays. I get an exception

```
com.mathworks.jmi.MatlabException: Error using ==> betainc X must be in the interval [0,1].
```

I have successfully used other functions like `mean` which returns the results fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what function you are trying to call. MATLAB does not come with an OLS function.
At some point MATLABS betainc() is called with an incorrect first argument.

Your best option is to set a breakpoint in your OLS function and see what is passed in as first and second argument.

And yes, using the unsupported Matlabcontrol it is possible to debug the MATLAB side.